# Static methods in abstract class?

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I recently learned from a video that it's a good practice to turn a Java class into abstract if all of its methods are static for performance reasons.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Comment: It's simply a mechanism to restrict anyone from instantiating the class. There are no performance reasons for this.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion whether it's "good practice" or not. Arguably it's confusing to make a class abstract if you don't intend to inherit from it.

Comment: Making the class `final` and the constructor private (and potentially throw an exception like `UnsupportedOperationException`) I find is more explicit about the intention of ‘don’t instantiate this’, but documentation exists for a reason, and if anyone wants to they can get around whatever hurdles you throw up there.

Comment: What's the source of this video? I think people have answered you with an after the fact excuse. You wouldn't make a class abstract to prevent instantiation. You would make the constructor private. Making the class final is a bit overkill, because static methods aren't inherited in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to prevent people from creating instances of the class. Java code is expected to create lots of objects that are useful for a short time and get garbage-collected, so it is hard to say this is any kind of substantial performance win. It seems more like a way to communicate the intention behind a class.

Another alternative is, instead of making the class abstract, make the class final. This is the approach taken in JDK code, for instance, java.lang.Math:

```
public final class Math {

    /**
     * Don't let anyone instantiate this class.
     */
    private Math() {}
```

With either of these approaches you should give the class a private constructor. That prevents anyone from instantiating it and makes it clear the class's purpose is to provide a home for the static methods. The downside here is code coverage tools tend to report the constructor as uncovered.

A third alternative, as of Java 8, is to put the static methods on an interface. Any methods with an implementation that aren't default get assumed to be static methods. The advantage of that approach is there is no constructor to make private, and the code coverage tools will be happy.

With an abstract class (but without the private constructor), or an interface, there is also the possibility of extending or implementing the type to make all the static methods available without static imports. [See this link for an example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/declare-static-variables-and-methods-in-an-abstract-class-in-java). With the java.lang.Math approach that isn't an option.

Comment: "This is likely to prevent people from creating instances of the class." do you have a source for that?

Comment: @matt: this sonarqube rule lists abstract classes as one means to implement utility classes: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/design/RSPEC-1118

Comment: It doesn't really say that though, it says utility classes should not have a public constructor so they cannot be instantiated. It doesn't say anything about why the class would be abstract just, "*Even abstract utility classes, which can be extended, should not have public constructors.*"

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make it an abstract if it has static methods. if you make it an abstract class then no one can instantiate this class.

on the other hand, you can declare a class with a private constructor, so no one, not even a subclass, can instantiate an instance of your class.

```
 public class A
 {
    private A()
    {
       throw new RuntimeException("Instantiation of MyUtility is not 
       allowed!");
     }

    public static void aMethod()
    {
      // Your method here.
    }
  }
```

Comment: "...if you make it an abstract class then no one can instantiate this class." but that isn't true.

Comment: @matt: people can instantiate your class if you provide only a private constructor, make it throw an exception, have initialiser blocks that exit the JVM. The intention is to make it harder for someone to instantiate and rely on documentation/their good sense to take the hint. If they want to, they can get around whatever you do.